# Spring Data JPA named stored procedure REF CURSOR doesn't work with SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm working on a project that requires both Rest Web Services and SOAP Web Services. The problem is that when I tried to call the stored procedure using SOAP, I get this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: result;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: result

while it works perfectly fine using the Rest web service. Is there a way around it?

This is now I defined the stored procedure:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = VACompanyProfile.namedQuery_GetCompanyProfileAllowed,
    procedureName = "COMPANY_PROFILE",
    parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = ResultSet.class, name = "result"),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "company_code_in")
    }
  )

@Procedure(name = VACompanyProfile.namedQuery_GetCompanyProfileAllowed)
ResultSet getClientIDAllowed(String companyCode);
```

my Pom

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>

<sourceRoot>src/main/java/wsdlentity</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>

<wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/VirtualAccount.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```